# SQL Can't get User Input?

Tags: postgresql

I'm learning SQL. I've heard that it's not possible to get user input in SQL? How are login and sign-ups made then? I'd really like to know if I just heard wrong or if you have to use another language or something like that to get input. Please explain? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL is a language that is used to communicate with relational databases. You cannot write a program in SQL, so you will have to use some other language for that. To interact with a database, use the database API of that language, which will allow you to send SQL statements to the database.

Comment: So what language should I use? Would Python or HTML//CSS work?

Comment: You need a programming language like Perl or Java or C or many others, not a markup language like HTML.